# Binding to widget

Tags: tkinter

I am having problems binding key events to TkInter widgets.
I have tried many example from the websites, but with no luck.
I notice that none of the examples are using classes.
I am defining my GUI inside a class; could that effect the binding?
If anyone could let me know id be grateful.
thanks

```
self.label_var = StringVar()
self.label = CTkLabel(
    master=self.frame,
    width=label_width,
    height=height,
    fg_color=background,
    text_color=label_colour,
    textvariable=self.label_var,
)
self.label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(e))
```

The full class is as below. The idea was to wrap all the boiler-plate code together but also to allow me to have the label at either side of the switch.

```
class LabelledSwitch:
    def __init__(
        self,
        frame: CTkFrame,
        row: int,
        column: int,
        padx: Tuple[int, int],
        pady: Tuple[int, int],
        width: int,
        height: int,
        background: str,
        label_width: int,
        label_colour: str,
        label_align: str,
        label_left: bool,
        switch_width: int,
        align: str,
        callback,
    ):

        self.frame = CTkFrame(
            frame, width=width, height=height, bg_color=background, fg_color=None
        )
        self.frame.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=0, pady=0)

        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(index=0, weight=0)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(index=1, weight=1)

        if align == "LEFT":
            self.frame.grid(sticky="w")
        if align == "RIGHT":
            self.frame.grid(sticky="e")
        if align == "CENTER":
            self.frame.grid(sticky="")
        if align == "STRETCH":
            self.frame.grid(sticky="we")

        self.label_var = StringVar()
        self.label = CTkLabel(
            master=self.frame,
            width=label_width,
            height=height,
            fg_color=background,
            text_color=label_colour,
            textvariable=self.label_var,
        )
        self.label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(e))

        if label_left:
            self.label.grid(
                row=0,
                column=0,
                padx=(padx[0], 0),
                pady=(pady[0], pady[1]),
            )
        else:
            self.label.grid(
                row=0,
                column=1,
                padx=(5, padx[1]),
                pady=(pady[0], pady[1]),
            )
        if label_align == "LEFT":
            self.label.configure(anchor="w")
        if label_align == "RIGHT":
            self.label.configure(anchor="e")
        if label_align == "CENTER":
            self.label.configure(anchor="we")
        if label_align == "STRETCH":
            self.label.configure(anchor="we")

        self.switch_var = StringVar()
        self.switch = CTkSwitch(
            master=self.frame,
            width=switch_width,
            height=height,
            background="GREEN",
            bg_color=background,
            text="",
            variable=self.switch_var,
            onvalue="on",
            offvalue="off",
            command=callback,
        )

        if label_left:
            self.switch.grid(
                row=0,
                column=1,
                padx=(5, padx[1]),
                pady=(pady[0], pady[1]),
            )
        else:
            self.switch.grid(
                row=0,
                column=0,
                padx=(padx[0], 0),
                pady=(pady[0], pady[1]),
            )

        if align == "LEFT":
            self.switch.grid(sticky="w")
        if align == "RIGHT":
            self.switch.grid(sticky="e")
        if align == "CENTER":
            self.switch.grid(sticky="we")
        if align == "STRETCH":
            self.switch.grid(sticky="we")
```

Comment: There's not quite enough code here to help us answer your question. Please include the class you're defining and any error tracebacks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of the CTkLabel widget. When you click on the widget, you actually click on a label embedded on the widget. Since your binding isn't on that internal embedded label, your binding won't trigger.

You can see this by printing out the value of `self.label`, and then adding this binding:

```
root.bind_all("<1>", lambda event: print(event.widget))
```

The output will show that `self.label` is named something like `.!root.!frame.!ctklabel`, but the widget that receives the click is something like `.!root.!frame.!ctklabel.!label`

You should probably file a bug with the customtkinter project.

As a workaround, you can bind to all of the inner child widgets of the label like so:

```
for child in self.label.winfo_children():
    child.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(e))
```

Comment: That certainly solves it for me for now. thank you!